# Cadena de entrada no tiene formato corrrecto. (Excepcion)

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
    if (lCliente.Direccion.Numero != null)
     numeroCliente = int.Parse(lCliente.Direccion.Numero);
```

El problema es que cuando la dirección el número tiene algun caracter como un . o un - me salta este error.

Como puedo controlar la excepción?

Gracias!

PD: Mi idea es que solo pueda aceptar valores numéricos. Pero el valor numérico puede ser de más de un dato. Es decir tiene que dar como válido 170, pero no por ejemplo 170-2. Tengo que evitar guiones, puntos comas.. letras...

Comment: No es solo un número.. pueden ser más de uno.. y nunca se el valor... el ejemplo que me ponéis no me sirve.

Comment: Por que no te sirve? No importan los numeros que sean, la clave es que debes usar `TryParse` que devuelve true o false dependiendo de si ha conseguido parsear a int o no